# registering app / deploying with Google App Engine and Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine, gae-eclipse-plugin

I am trying to deploy a very simple app on app engine using Eclipse and the provided Google plugin.

I created the simplest possible android app which starts the RegisterActivity generated by the plugin, where I did plug the ID, Api Key and project number. I then click on the button but I get this error message :

```
11-25 16:53:50.372: E/com.example.a123.GCMIntentService(25146): Exception received when attempting to register with server at https://blabla-my-app67.appspot.com/_ah/api/
11-25 16:53:50.372: E/com.example.a123.GCMIntentService(25146): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
11-25 16:53:50.372: E/com.example.a123.GCMIntentService(25146): Not Found
```

Although, the console tells me that there is one instance up and running and the LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN variable in CloudEndpointUtils.java is set to false.

Indeed, it seems that for instance this URL : http://blabla-my-app67.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer%20pagereturns me 404 error.

How is that possible and what can I be doing wrong ?

Thank you a lot in advance.

Al

EDIT :

blabla-my-app67.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer is not a 404 but http://blabla-my-app67.appspot.com/_ah/api is.

**EDIT SOLUTION :**
You absolutly need to be compiling with java JRE 1.7 !!

Comment: Found solution : You absolutly need to be compiling with java JRE 1.7 !!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

You absolutly need to be compiling with java JRE 1.7 !! 1.8 does not work..